# How do I format the directions output listing in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, formatting

I'm new to Google Maps API V3 and I have to use it to replace an older mapping app in one of our systems.

I've implemented a basic routing screen using the example at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

The basics are working well.  The one thing that's bothering me is that I cannot find any clear discussion in the API of how to format the directions output listing.  Nothing I've tried so far seems to affect it.

I'm simply doing a DirectionsRenderer.setPanel(div name) where the div has no properties other than a width of 1025px.

My chief irritations are that the directions themselves are only about 2/3 the width of the div and the text in the middle column looks like it's center justified.  (The top and bottom of the list, the origin and destination addresses are the correct width.)

Is there any way to customize this or am I using too simple a model for my page?

Answer (score 1):

The data used to render the directions panel is available in the result returned from the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), you can render it however you like by doing it manually.

Very simple example:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_icons_draggable.html

Custom Renderer:

```
function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
        var detailsPanel = document.getElementById("direction_details");
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
        detailsPanel.innerHTML = '<ul>';

        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
        }
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            detailsPanel.innerHTML += "<li>"+steps[j].instructions;
            var dist_dur = "";
            if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;"+steps[j].distance.text;
            if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;"+steps[j].duration.text;
            if (dist_dur != "") {
              detailsPanel.innerHTML += "("+dist_dur+")<br /></li>";
            } else {
              detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</li>";

            }
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



            }
          }
        }

        detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</ul>"
        polyline.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();

      }
      else alert(status);
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still lost.  I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is compatible with your example.  I've added your RenderCustomDirections largely unmodified.  No matter what I try I cannot get that function to fire.  It doesn't look like I can post the actual code here so just let me repeat that my original code is modeled after the ref my original post.  I neglected to mention that I have a provideRouteAlternatives: true in the request options.

Comment: Actually it looks like this whole question is moot.  Due to time constraints we'll probably go with the default Google behavior. Much simpler.  Thanks to everyone who responded.